# how to display one controller show action in another controller action in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using two controller incident and incident_list, i am displaying all incidents in incident_list/index page when click on show button in each incident i want to display that incident details

**IncidentListController**

```
def show
   @incidents = Incident.all
   @incident = Incident.find(params[:id])
   render "incidents/show"
 end
```

**IncidentController**

```
def show
  @incidents = Incident.all
  @incident = Incident.find(params[:id])
 end
```

**incidnet_lists/index.html.erb**

```
<table>
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
   <thead >
  <tr>
      <th class="c2">Case ID</th>
      <th class="c2">Call Type</th>
      <th class="c2">Number of People</th>
      <th class="c2"></th>

  </tr>
 </thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><%= inc.id %> </td>
    <td><%= inc.call_type %> </td>
    <td><%= inc.no_of_people %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', @incidents %></td>

  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

**incidents/show.html.erb**

```
 <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <td class= "c2" > Case Id </td>
       <td class= "c2"> Caller Name </td>
       <td class="c2"> Contact Number </td>
       <td class= "c2"> Calling For </td>
       <td class="c2"> Call Type </td>
      <tr>
      </thead>
     <tbody>
       <% @incidents.each do |inc| %>
       <tr>
         <td> <%= inc.id %> </td>
         <td> <%= inc.caller_name %></td>
         <td> <%= inc.contact_number %></td>
         <td> <%= inc.for_whom %> </td>
         <td> <%= inc.call_type %> </td>
       </tr>
       <% end %>
     </tbody>
   </table>
```

when click on show button in the incident_list page incident show page should be display

Answer (score 1):

Your situation is perfectly covered by REST approach.

According to that approach you should have the single `IncidentsController` controller. Then you should have

1. `show` action which would expose particular incident to `show.html.erb` view as `@incident` instance variable
2. `index` action which would expose the list of all (or some) incidents to `index.html.erb` view as `@incidents` instance variable.

So you don't need and should not call some controller's action from another controller's action.

It's the "Rails Way", it's the "REST Way". It's the way how one should do that.

The simplest tip in your situation is generate rails scaffold for your incidents resources and use the generated files properly to set up things.

```
rails generate scaffold Incident
```

Comment: thank you, already i have created scaffold for incident, i dont want to show incidents in incident index, i wanted to display that list in incident_lists/index.html.erb only

Comment: Ok, in your `index.html` you could do something like

`@incidents.each do |incident| <%= link_to 'Show', incident %> end`

I'm just telling that your current setup is not the correct way to do such things. And you may want to do it in the correct way (for what Rails framework was designed actually). However it's totally your decision.